# Does SolrJ perform caching?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using Solr in my web application as search engine. I use the DataImportHandler to automatically import data from my database into the search index. When the DataImportHandler adds new data, the data is successfully added to the index, but it isn't returned when I query the index using SolrJ: I have to restart my application server for the data to be found by SolrJ. Is there some kind of caching going on? I used SolrJ in embedded mode. Here's my SolrJ code:

```
private static final SolrServer solrServer = initSolrServer();
private static SolrServer initSolrServer() {
    try {
        CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
        coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
        EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "");
        return server;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error initializing SOLR server", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to query I do the following:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(keyword);
QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(query);
```

As you can see, my SolrServer is declared as static. Should I create a new EmbeddedSolrServer for each query instead? I'm afraid that will incur a big performance penalty.

Comment: SolrJ does not cache.  I'm not familiar w/DIH - but are you sure you are committing?  Finally - you will probably get more developer love over on solr-user@apache.org

Answer (score 0):

Standard configuration of Solr Server doesn't provide auto-commit. If you have solrconfig.xml file, look for the commented tag "autoCommit". If not, then after each document added you can call `server.commit();`, although with large stream of documents this could prove a big performance issue (as `commit` is relatively heavy operation).

If you are using it in a web application, I'd advise using solr-x.x.war in your deploy instead of EmbeddedSolrServer. This will provide you with rich Http interface for updating, administrating and searching the index.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to commit method - I have data committed, but queries still return same results even though I've disabled caches in solrconfig.xml (filterCache, queryResultsCache and documentCache).